# Issue with Hashes and Arrays of Datetimes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a list of Datetimes for available booking in a Rails app. I wrote a quick function to group the Datetimes by day in order to organize them for display in my view.

My Code:

```
def self.sort_by_day(times)
    day = times[0].strftime("%d")
    array = []
    days_hash = Hash.new
    counter = 0
    while counter < times.size
      if times[counter].strftime("%d") == day
        array.push(times[counter])
        counter += 1
      else
        days_hash[times[counter].strftime("%d")] = array
        logger.debug "#{days_hash}"
        array.clear
        array << times[counter]
        day = times[counter].strftime("%d")
        counter += 1
      end
    end
    days_hash    
end
```

> {"18"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 09:00:00
>   -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 17:00:00 -0500], "19"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "20"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "21"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "22"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "24"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "25"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "26"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "27"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "28"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "29"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500], "31"=>[Fri, 29 Jan 2016 08:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan
>   2016 09:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   11:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 12:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   13:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 14:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   15:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016 16:00:00 -0500, Fri, 29 Jan 2016
>   17:00:00 -0500]}

My code is overwriting the hash values of previous days each time a new key/value pair is assigned.I previously got similar results using arrays. What am I doing wrong here and how is the hash overwriting previous values?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Could you explain better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of Rails `DateTime` object, and you want to group them by `day` of month and have the resultant hash ordered by `day` value, then, you can do the following:

```
ary.sort_by(&:day).group_by(&:day)
```

---

Working example for illustration is provided below:

```
require "pp"
require "active_support/core_ext/date_time"

ary = [
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 12, 13),
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 10, 10),
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 11, 10),
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 11, 11),
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 11, 12),
        (DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2015, 12, 13),
      ]

pp ary.sort_by(&:day).group_by(&:day)
#=> {10=>[Sat, 10 Nov 2015 00:00:00 +0530, Sat, 10 Oct 2015 00:00:00 +0530],
#    11=>[Wed, 11 Nov 2015 00:00:00 +0530],
#    12=>[Thu, 12 Nov 2015 00:00:00 +0530],
#    13=>[Sun, 13 Dec 2015 00:00:00 +0530, Sun, 13 Dec 2015 00:00:00 +0530]}
```